# Tabs in TabLayout not filling up entire ActionBar

Tags: java, android, tabs

I am using a `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` to display `ActionBar tabs` following the guide [Google Play Style Tabs using TabLayout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout), however my tabs are squished to the left side of the ActionBar, shown below:

[image]
And I would like them to take up the whole bar with equal widths. I've made only a few minor changes to the guide:

In activity_main.xml a style was created to show the ActionBar:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
  android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  style="@style/AppTheme"
  app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

Here is the styles.xml code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
  <item name="tabIndicatorColor">#ffff0030</item>
</style>
```

Also, my `MainActivity` now extends `AppCompatActivity` instead of a `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: Your TabLayout is embedded within a LinearLayout as shown in the guide?

Comment: Yes it is with the LinearLayout

Comment: add this will work:`app:tabGravity="fill"`

Comment: **app:tabGravity:"fill"** 
and
**app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"**  did for me !

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can refer to the [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html).

`GRAVITY_CENTER` Gravity used to lay out the tabs in the center of the TabLayout.

`GRAVITY_FILL` Gravity used to fill the TabLayout as much as possible.

`MODE_FIXED` Fixed tabs display all tabs concurrently and are best used with content that benefits from quick pivots between tabs.

`MODE_SCROLLABLE` Scrollable tabs display a subset of tabs at any given moment, and can contain longer tab labels and a larger number of tabs.

Set this in your code or your layout xml.

```
app:tabGravity="center"
app:tabMode="fixed"
```

or

```
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
```

Generally, using the code like blow can work without setting `tabGravity` and `tabMode`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: I took out the line `app:tabMode="scrollable"` and it resolved the issue.

Comment: I too can confirm that removing app:tabMode="" from the XML file resolved everything. Changing the tabMode value would still make the the tabs appear squished. It was only resolved by not including this attribute at all.

Comment: i have a dynamic tabs content, it works when i have multiple tabs but when there is only one tab the text isnt shown to the fullest (the tab only spanns to the icon width) is there a way to tackle this issue

Answer (score 44):

Simple answer which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843775/tab-not-taking-full-width-on-tablet-device-using-android-support-design-widget).

You just put this in your xml code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Comment: You are killing it! The tabMaxWidth parameter helped me to fix a non working device. app:tabGravity="fill" & app:tabMode="fixed" was not enough for one of my device.

Comment: this fixed a problem for me in landscape mode (even though it was working fine in portrait)

Comment: app:tabMaxWidth="0dp" was the solution I needed. Thanks!

Comment: app:tabMaxWidth="0dp" saved me. Thanks

Comment: for mentioning `app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"` +1 !!

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to MainActivity:

```
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add - app:tabGravity="fill" property in the xml.

For Example -

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it works

```
 app:tabGravity="fill"
 app:tabMode="fixed"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Set TabLayout width to match Parent**

Like this.

```
<TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"/>
```