# Tabs don't take full width using Design Support Library

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

I'm following [this tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout) that explains how to implement the new TabLayout included in the Google Design Support Library. Here's my app:

[image]

As can be seen in the above screenshot, my tabs are not taking full width of screen.

How can I fix it?

Here's my activity xml:
(My Java code is the same as the one in [the tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout). In the following code my tablayout and viewpager are inside a FrameLayout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<!-- your content layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Toolbar instead of ActionBar so the drawer can slide on top -->
    <!-- If you want to have dark background for options buttons remove the popup theme -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
    <!-- Real content goes here -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_view_header"
        app:menu="@layout/nav_view_menu"
        app:theme="@style/MyTheme.NavMenu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

EDIT:

After adding `app:tabGravity="center"` and changing `app:tabMode` to `fixed`, here's how the app looks:

[image]

I need them to fill the width.

**This question is not a duplicate. the other answer did not fix my issue.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tabs in TabLayout not filling up entire ActionBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721498/tabs-in-tablayout-not-filling-up-entire-actionbar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

> `GRAVITY_CENTER` Gravity used to lay out the tabs in the center of the
>   TabLayout.
>
> `GRAVITY_FILL` Gravity used to fill the TabLayout as much as possible.
>
> `MODE_FIXED` Fixed tabs display all tabs concurrently and are best
>   used with content that benefits from quick pivots between tabs.
>
> `MODE_SCROLLABLE` Scrollable tabs display a subset of tabs at any
>   given moment, and can contain longer tab labels and a larger number of
>   tabs.

Just set this in your `TabLayout`:

```
app:tabMode="fixed"
```

**Edit:**

I'm using this and it's working:

```
             <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

**Seems like you don't need to set anything.**

proof:

[image]

Btw, you can check this also:

```
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

Comment: Yes, you would have to use `gravity_center`!

Comment: Remove that scrollable.that should work then i guess: this line : `app:tabMode="scrollable"`

Comment: I already did. I changed `tabMode` to `fixed` as you suggested. it doesn't work.

Comment: I found a solution. Check my answer.

Comment: You are right saying that without xml attributes it works, but you are wrong suggesting tabGravity="center". The right combination is tabGravity="fill" and tabMode="fixed" (which is the default).

Comment: OK, you're right. Without setting anything it would work. My bad. Accepted your answer.

Comment: Thank you for being honest by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add these to both xml and java:

In Java:

```
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

And in XML for TabLayout:

```
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What is the difference with my answer? :)

Comment: The Java code is a must. Gravity needs to be set in both xml and java. In xml it needs to be set to `center` and in java to `fill`

Comment: You won't need that, my answer is working.without these two!

Comment: @LinX64, Well I tried that like 10 times and It wasn't working.

Comment: So, the question is duplicate.you could take a look at that question i've already commented as the duplicate.such as: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30721642/4409113

Answer (score -1):

set `TabLayoutMode` like this:

```
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
```

Comment: How is this different than setting `app:tabMode="fixed"` which I already did?