# expand the width of tab layout according to screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

how can i expand the width of my tab layout ? right now what i have is this:

on a tablet (1024 x 600) :

[image]

mt tabLayout xml :

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e4e4e4"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewpager"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:clickable="false" />
```

on a phone (Nexus 4) its expanding as desired:

[image]

how can i expand it same as it expanded in phones ??

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721498/tabs-in-tablayout-not-filling-up-entire-actionbar

Comment: use tabMode=fixed, tabGravity=fill

Comment: @CSmith i tired this `       tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);`  but it doesn't seems to work