# Android fill tab columns on android 4 on tablet size

Tags: android

this screen shot is for android 4.3 on tablet size and i'm trying to fill columns to fix them like with `match_parent`

[image]

my xml layout:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
       android:id="@+id/categoriesTabsLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
       app:tabGravity="fill"
       app:tabMode="fixed"
       app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
       app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
       />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add **[tabMaxWidth](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#attr_android.support.design:tabMaxWidth)**.

> The maximum width for tabs.
>
> May be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended
>   with a unit such as "14.5sp". Available units are: px (pixels), dp
>   (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred
>   font size), in (inches), and mm (millimeters) .

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
      app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
       />
```

You can check **[Tabs in TabLayout not filling up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30721806/3395198)** .